# GIT-TF Could not get principal for kerberos 5 credentials (No credentials cache file found)

Tags: git, tfs, git-tf

I'm trying to set up git-tf on osx. I have everything configured correctly and am now trying to clone an existing TFS repo into git-tf.

I am running the following command:

```
git tf clone https://tfs-url.net/tfs $/path/to/workspaceOrWhateverTFSCallsIt
```

I enter my username and password but I always get a timed out message:

```
Connecting to TFS...
git-tf: connect timed out
```

Even if the --verbose flag is set. Even if I enter utter nonsense for the un/pw combo. Handy that.

In the logs I get this:

```
2014-01-06 16:32:48,139 INFO  [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.jni.loader.NativeLoader) Loaded /Users/wayne/Git-Tf/native/macosx/libnative_auth.jnilib from user-specified directory
2014-01-06 16:32:48,140 INFO  [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.jni.natives.NativeAuthMethods) Loaded GSSAPI library: libgssapi_krb5.dylib
2014-01-06 16:32:48,155 WARN  [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.jni.natives.NativeAuthMethods) Could not get principal for kerberos 5 credentials (No credentials cache file found)
2014-01-06 16:32:48,159 WARN  [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.jni.natives.NativeAuthMethods) Could not get principal for kerberos 5 credentials (No credentials cache file found)
2014-01-06 16:32:48,173 INFO  [main] (com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.PullCommand) Default credentials are not available for authentication (no ticket)
2014-01-06 16:33:00,760 INFO  [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.jni.loader.NativeLoader) Loaded /Users/wayne/Git-Tf/native/macosx/libnative_console.jnilib from user-specified directory
2014-01-06 16:33:06,091 INFO  [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.jni.loader.NativeLoader) Loaded /Users/wayne/Git-Tf/native/macosx/libnative_misc.jnilib from user-specified directory
2014-01-06 16:33:06,100 INFO  [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.core.config.httpclient.DefaultHTTPClientFactory) HttpClient configured for https://tfs-mobile.ocseths.net/tfs, authenticating as DEV01\AX81dev
2014-01-06 16:33:37,045 WARN  [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.core.TFSTeamProjectCollection) Error getting data provider
com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: connect timed out
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.mappers.TECoreExceptionMapper.map(TECoreExceptionMapper.java:105)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.mappers.RegistrationExceptionMapper.map(RegistrationExceptionMapper.java:23)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.registration.RegistrationData.newFromServer(RegistrationData.java:70)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.registration.RegistrationClient.getRegistrationData(RegistrationClient.java:645)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.registration.RegistrationClient.getRegistrationEntries(RegistrationClient.java:151)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.registration.RegistrationClient.getRegistrationEntries(RegistrationClient.java:135)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.PreFrameworkServerDataProvider.findServiceLocation(PreFrameworkServerDataProvider.java:289)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.PreFrameworkServerDataProvider.locationForCurrentConnection(PreFrameworkServerDataProvider.java:264)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.TFSTeamProjectCollection.getServerDataProvider(TFSTeamProjectCollection.java:177)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.TFSConnection.ensureAuthenticated(TFSConnection.java:739)
    at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.framework.Command.getConnection(Command.java:400)
    at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.framework.Command.getConnection(Command.java:372)
    at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.framework.Command.getConnection(Command.java:358)
    at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.framework.Command.getVersionControlClient(Command.java:520)
    at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.framework.Command.getVersionControlService(Command.java:538)
    at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.PullCommand.run(PullCommand.java:154)
    at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.Main.main(Main.java:328)
Caused by: com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.exceptions.TransportException: connect timed out
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequestInternal(SOAPService.java:743)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequest(SOAPService.java:475)
    at ms.tfs.services.registration._03._RegistrationSoap12Service.getRegistrationEntries(_RegistrationSoap12Service.java:105)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.registration.RegistrationData.newFromServer(RegistrationData.java:65)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.config.httpclient.internal.DefaultSSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultSSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:77)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:862)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1690)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:495)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:197)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:464)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:376)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequestInternal(SOAPService.java:590)
    ... 17 more
2014-01-06 16:33:37,048 WARN  [main] (git-tf) Error executing command: pull
com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: connect timed out
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.mappers.TECoreExceptionMapper.map(TECoreExceptionMapper.java:105)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.mappers.RegistrationExceptionMapper.map(RegistrationExceptionMapper.java:23)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.registration.RegistrationData.newFromServer(RegistrationData.java:70)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.registration.RegistrationClient.getRegistrationData(RegistrationClient.java:645)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.registration.RegistrationClient.getRegistrationEntries(RegistrationClient.java:151)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.registration.RegistrationClient.getRegistrationEntries(RegistrationClient.java:135)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.PreFrameworkServerDataProvider.findServiceLocation(PreFrameworkServerDataProvider.java:289)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.PreFrameworkServerDataProvider.locationForCurrentConnection(PreFrameworkServerDataProvider.java:264)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.TFSTeamProjectCollection.getServerDataProvider(TFSTeamProjectCollection.java:177)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.TFSConnection.ensureAuthenticated(TFSConnection.java:739)
    at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.framework.Command.getConnection(Command.java:400)
    at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.framework.Command.getConnection(Command.java:372)
    at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.framework.Command.getConnection(Command.java:358)
    at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.framework.Command.getVersionControlClient(Command.java:520)
    at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.framework.Command.getVersionControlService(Command.java:538)
    at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.PullCommand.run(PullCommand.java:154)
    at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.Main.main(Main.java:328)
Caused by: com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.exceptions.TransportException: connect timed out
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequestInternal(SOAPService.java:743)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequest(SOAPService.java:475)
    at ms.tfs.services.registration._03._RegistrationSoap12Service.getRegistrationEntries(_RegistrationSoap12Service.java:105)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.registration.RegistrationData.newFromServer(RegistrationData.java:65)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.config.httpclient.internal.DefaultSSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultSSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:77)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:862)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1690)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:495)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:197)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:464)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:376)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequestInternal(SOAPService.java:590)
    ... 17 more
```

Is there anything I need to do on the TFS side to allow me to authenticate through git-tf?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't authentication, your problem is that you can't reach the server.  "Connection timed out indicates that the server could not be reached.

Double check the URL you are using to connect, including the port number.  Ensure that the server has a hole opened in the firewall.  Ensure that you can connect from a different TFS client, like Visual Studio or Team Explorer Everywhere.

Comment: I can connect on that URL using the eclipse TFS plugin.

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of the connection dialog from the TFS plug-in for Eclipse?

Comment: What should the second parameter be? Should I be using team project collections, team projects or the branch name from the branch properties?

Comment: Sorted it - I was not using the correct param for the second item